# Shortcut to take last inserted value. rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have,

```
@post = Post.all
```

I need the last inserted value in the array `@post` according to the field `created_at`.any shortcut for this other than `@post.each {|a| some_calculations}`

Comment: See the accepted answer on this SO-question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224619/rails-finding-notes-by-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@post.sort{|x,y| x.created_at <=> y.created_at}.last
```

Comment: And I got more simplified answer by user420504
@post.max_by {|x| x.created_at }

Comment: :D And this is the last one . @post.max_by(&:created_at)

Comment: For posterity: this should not be the accepted answer. You do not want to be sorting your entire post collection in ruby, you want the database to do it for you. Victor's answers are correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
@post = Post.order("created_at").last     #sort by created_at
```

or

```
@post = Post.last         #sort by ID
```

Comment: Isn't this only correct if assuming that ``id`` and ``created_at`` actually follows each other?

Comment: @ChristianWattengård sometimes you may have custom ID. For general purpose, `.last` should do just fine.

Comment: Yes. I agree. But you never know ;)

Comment: Well, by all means, just use the `order("any_filter")` to suit your preference. ;)

Comment: You are talking about retrieving from database.But I want to process the array, @post,Not during database operations.Any idea?

Comment: Not understand. Mind to revise your question, or show more code?

Comment: Would this work for you? `@post.max_by {|x| x.created_at }` This would do the processing on the array after all the records are retrieved. Ofcourse this is going to be more expensive than doing the sql query itself especially for a large number of records.